# Synchronized collection vs synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I have a class container containing a collection which is going to be used by multiple threads:

```
public class Container{

    private Map<String, String> map;

    //ctor, other methods reading the map

    public void doSomeWithMap(String key, String value){
        //do some threads safe action
        map.put(key, value);
        //do something else, also thread safe
    }
}
```

What would be better, to declare the method `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized void doSomeWithMap(String key, String value)
```

or to use standard thread-safe decorator?

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
```

Comment: if you do not need to handle the concurrency  by yourself , then chech this map here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Neither - Use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Not clear, why is synchronizing the method a wrong thing?

Comment: @St.Antario - Its not good because you will be locking on the entire map instance whereas in `ConcurrentHashMap` you will be looking on *specific segments* which is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, synchronizing the map will protect most access to it without having to think about it further. However, the "synchronized map" is not safe for iteration which may be an issue depending on your use case. [It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-)

Consider using [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) if that will meet your use case.

If there is other state to this object that needs to be protected from concurrency errors, then you will need to use synchronized or a `Lock`.

Comment: So, the primary difference between [synxhronizedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) is that the acces for read is not synchronized, right? So it gives us performance overhead in comparison with concurrentHashMap...

Comment: @St.Antario `ConcurrentHashMap` uses separate locks for groups of hash bins, by default 16 I believe. This means generally less lock contention since the implementation can compute the hash of the key without contention and then only lock 1/16th of the map. ConcurrentHashMap also allows thread-safe iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If your `doSomeWithMap` method will access the map *more than once*, you **must** synchronize the `doSomeWithMap` method. If the *only* access is the `put()` call shown, then it's better to use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Note that "more than once" is any call, and an iterator is by nature many "gets".

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the implementation of [`SynchronizedMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2554), you'll see that it's simply a map wrapping a non thread-safe map that uses a mutex before calling any method

```
public V get(Object key) {
  synchronized (mutex) {return m.get(key);}
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
  synchronized (mutex) {return m.put(key, value);}
}

public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
  synchronized (mutex) {
    if (entrySet==null)
      entrySet = new SynchronizedSet<>(m.entrySet(), mutex);
    return entrySet;
  }
}
```

If all you want is protecting `get` and `put`, this implementation does it for you.

However it's not suitable if you want a Map that can be iterated over and updated by two or more threads, in which case you should use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the other things you do inside `doSomeWithMap` would cause problems if done concurrently by different threads (for example, they update class-level variables) then you should synchronise the whole method. If this is not the case then you should use a synchronised `Map` in order to minimise the length of time the synchronisation lock is left in place.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have the block to be synchronized upon the requirement. Please note this.

When you use synchronized Collection like `ConcurrentHashMap` or Collection's method like `synchronizedMap()`, `synchronizedList()` etc, only the `Map`/`List` is synchronized. To explain little further,

Consider,

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> synchMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
```

This makes the map's **get operation** to be synchronous and not the objects inside it.

```
Object o = synchMap.get("1");// Object referenced by o is not synchronized. Only the map is.
```

If you want to protect the objects inside the Map, then you also have to put the code inside the synchronized block. This is good to remember as many people forget to safe guard the object in most cases.

Look at this for little info too [Collection's synchronizedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-)